# What is the HP and mana regen rate in Orna?

Tags: orna

I've noticed that if I leave the app closed, my HP and mana points regen over time. I always left it closed long enough that it seems that it is fully regen after at least 6 hours.

Does it regen a fixed amount per hour or does it fill all your points after a specific amount of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You regain 1% hp and mana per minute if you close the game app, so you regenerate in the background.

Source:
https://www.ornalegends.com/home/the-ultimate-ornarpg-beginner-basics-guide

Answer (score -3):

Your character does regenerate set amount of HP and MP per time. Some classes regenerate more than others.

Comment: What is this "set amount"?

Comment: I couldn't find it in any resource. Also the question didn't require a number.

Comment: @Markol The title of the question asked for the rate, which would be a flat rate or percentage. Please update your answer to include this information, currently it does not provide much information that wasn't already in the question.

Comment: I see, the title does want a number.

Comment: I am new to this platform - should I post a partial answer if there is no other answer to the question ?